# Laravel use an icon to delete content

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following delete button:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['tasks.destroy', $type->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Erase this task?', ['class' => 'delete']) !!}
{!!Form::close() !!}
```

And now I would like to not use a button, but an icon to delete content. I would like to use this button: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/remove-sign/

```
<i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> icon-remove-sign
```

The sign should be blue and small.

How do I do that? I only get error messages relating to models as a result. But when I dont make any changes it works perfectly.

Can someone give me an example of how to make the picture point to a delete route?

Answer (score 0):

The form helper does not allow you to add HTML to it. Use a simple HTML button:

```html
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['tasks.destroy', $type->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
    <button class="delete">
        <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Erase this task
    </button>
{!!Form::close() !!}
```